# Flatten child array to parent property

Tags: typescript

I have grouped by data but need to convert it into flat structure

```
data = [
   {
      "Name":"Gorba Technology",
      "Product":"Dell",
      "City":[
         "Delhi",
         "Mumbai"
      ]
   },
   {
      "Name":"Suvidha Computer",
      "Product":"Lenovo",
      "City":[
         "Deoghar"
      ]
   },
   {
      "Name":"Sara Laptop",
      "Product":"Dell",
      "City":[
         "Noida",
         "Delhi"
      ]
   }
]
```

Desired output

```
[{"Name":"Gorba Technology","City":"Delhi"},
{"Name":"Gorba Technology","City":"Mumbai"},
{"Name":"Suvidha Computer","City":"Deoghar"},
{"Name":"Sara Laptop","City":"Noida"},
{"Name":"Sara Laptop","City":"Delhi"}]
```

I try to do this approach but not worked

```
var result = data.map(({Name, City}) => City.map(item => {Name, item}));
```

I try to use `flatMap` but in my code, I was getting errors by lint. so without using `flatMap` need to achieve the output

Answer (score 0):

You need `reduce` instead of map

```
data.reduce((acc, {Name, City}) => {
  City.each((city) => {
    acc.push({Name, City: city});
  });
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: getting error .each not a function

Comment: Mistake - forEach

Answer (score 0):

`map()` will always return the same number of items as your input array. That is not your requirement though.

One way to do this can be using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

You use destructure but for every list item you add multiple items into the array with the same `Name`:

```js
const data = [
   {
      "Name":"Gorba Technology",
      "Product":"Dell",
      "City":[
         "Delhi",
         "Mumbai"
      ]
   },
   {
      "Name":"Suvidha Computer",
      "Product":"Lenovo",
      "City":[
         "Deoghar"
      ]
   },
   {
      "Name":"Sara Laptop",
      "Product":"Dell",
      "City":[
         "Noida",
         "Delhi"
      ]
   }
]

var result = data.reduce((acc,{Name,City}) => { 
  const items = [];
  City.forEach(city=> {
  items.push({Name , City : city});
  });
  return [...acc,...items];
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
   {
      "Name":"Gorba Technology",
      "Product":"Dell",
      "City":[
         "Delhi",
         "Mumbai"
      ]
   },
   {
      "Name":"Suvidha Computer",
      "Product":"Lenovo",
      "City":[
         "Deoghar"
      ]
   },
   {
      "Name":"Sara Laptop",
      "Product":"Dell",
      "City":[
         "Noida",
         "Delhi"
      ]
   }
];

const transformedData = [];

data.forEach(el => {
  if (el?.City?.length) {
    el.City.forEach(ct => {
      const obj = {...el, City: ct};
      transformedData.push(obj);
    })
  }
});

console.log(transformedData);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).